# Solve this number theory problem without plugging in

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$a>b$

$b<c$

$a=2c$

If a,b, and c represent different integers in the statements above, which of the following statements must be true?

I. $ac>b^2$

I know that the above statement is true as if a and c =0 and b=-1 the statement works. But let's say I cannot imagine that a and c =0 and b=-1. In that case, how would I verify that $ac>b^2$?

Comment: I just edited the problem as my previous formatting left out the condition that $b<c$

Comment: Start with your first inequality, multiply by $b$, and use the second.

Comment: (1) If $a=0$, $b=-1$, $c=0$ then $ac<b^2$, making your statement *false* instead of true. (2) But if $a,b,c$ represent *different* integers, you cannot have both $a=0$ and $c=0$. (3) For the statement to be true, you must show that it holds for *all* choices of $a,b,c$. For the statement to be false, it is enough to fine *one* counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

What you are being asked is which statement ***must*** be true (no matter what the values of $a, b, c.$

The option you post cannot be proven true for all $a, b, c$, because it happens to be true *only for some* values of $a, b, c$,) e.g. $a = 4, c=2, b=1$, but it is ***not*** true *for all* $a, b, c$.

Counterexample to the posted claim: Take $a = 2, c = 1, b= -2$. Then

- $a > b$ since $2>-2$,
- $b<c$ since $-2 < 1$,
- $a = 2c$ since $2 = 2(1)$.

However, when we test the inequality at these values: $$ac\overset{?}{>}b^2$$ we find, instead, that $$ 2\cdot1 = 2\lt (-2)^2 = 4$$

So if there is an always-true statement option, it's not $(I.),\,$ the one you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I. is necessarily true. If $a = 2c$ then $a$ and $c$ have the same sign and therefore $ac$ will always be positive. Both $a$ and $c$ are greater than $b$ therefore $ac > b^2$.

Comment: Take $a=2,b=-2$ and $c=1.$ Then, $ac=2<4=b^2.$

Comment: It appears my answer is incorrect. Darn negatives.